# SonarQube results not displaying coverage details for all projects

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We have a private sonarqube instance setup on our infrastructure, we analyzed a project source code and see that analysis results shown in sonarqube dashboard do not include all projects as shown in VSTS code coverage results. The excluded projects aren't test projects. Details below,

- SonarQube version: 6.7.1, Community Edition
- SonarC# version:   6.8.2(build 4717)
- SonarQube VSTS task version : 3.2.0(4.1 version doesn't work at all)
- SonarScanner for MSBuild: 4.1
- Solution Version:    VS 2015
- VSTest Console.exe version: 14.0.25420.1

We want to understand if there's a way to find how and why these projects are excluded from code coverage analysis, and a way to force SonarQube to include a project in analysis.

Comment: You'll probably need to add some characteristics of the excluded and included projects @sandeepmanthri. Otherwise it's likely to be a pure guessing game.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam the projects being included are created using VS 2015 and are a mixture of class library and windows application projects. Projects excluded are test class libraries and windows applications. Not sure what other information can be helpful, please let me know what exact characteristics are you looking for.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam can you please let me know what else information would be required to check the issue further? I can send you the logs if that helps

Comment: Perhaps these projects are being [ignored as test projects](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Miscellaneous+Advanced+Usages)?